# Google Docs Document Private Comment

Tags: documents, google-docs, google-drive

I have access to a collaborative Google Docs document on which I would like to make notes in preparation for a meeting (I am not the document owner). I would like to avoid wasting paper, so I would prefer to put comments straight in Google Docs. However, I am just using these notes as reference for further discussion so I don't want anybody else to see them. The document may be changing so I would prefer not simply copying the document for my notes.

**Is there any way make comments on a Google Docs document that only I can see?** Is copying the document my only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying the document is your only option. See [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/EeVMsWRvuXw) and [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/6QpAh94tZXQ/3N8ZR6Y9NiUJ). I cannot find more recent posts concerning this matter, and it would be better if you post a thread on the same forum.

Comment: Thanks. The use case for the first linked thread is a bit different (I had found this one). That second linked thread applies (I had not seen this discussion), but it is old.

Comment: @smp7d Half a year I agree, but someone in that thread (actually a google employee) mentioned they would propose this to the team. I guess if the feature had been introduced, it would be more easy to find it. Like I said, try posting a thread on the google product forums.